# Is it possible to log in another local user using script?

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to log in a second user from a Windows Pro PC programmatically after startup.
My thought is to use Task Scheduler that will execute log-in script at startup, or if not possible, once the primary (Admin) user is logged in, the task scheduler runs a script to log in the second user (also admin).

Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Add some info about what you're trying to achieve. You can start specific application as other user or just log-in specific user on startup. Are this options enough or are you looking for specifically "log user_1, do something (what?), log user_2" workflow?

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that I can run a process as another user but that is not what I am after - I need to make the other user account login just as I would do if I were to switch users via GUI.

Comment: So, for full clarity. You want to: 1. log on as user_x. 2. Start some applications, etc. 3. Use virtual "switch user" option and 4. log on as user_y. Is it correct?

Comment: If that's the process to achieve it, yes. But this will also suffice:
Startup PC, run a script via Task Manager for example via startup trigger to virtually log in as user 1, user 2, user 3 (need 3 in total)

Comment: So I assume that you want to initiate this users after creation? In this case it should be enough to just invoke this users profiles. You can use this Powershell snippet for this: `Start-Process $process -Credential $cred -LoadUserProfile`. If it doesn't start logon scripts, you can probably re-run them inside this process: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31c68677-d0d2-450f-823e-3765236669cf/rerunning-a-users-logon-script-from-the-desktop

Comment: $process = "notepad.exe"
$user="user2"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user,$password
Start-Process $process -Credential $cred -LoadUserProfile
This works but just runs notepad as user2. Doesn't actually make the user2 to fully log in to Windows.